# ASUS PA328Q 4K monitor Windows and DisplayPort issue

Tags: windows, display, displayport, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an ASUS PA328Q 4K monitor plugged onto the DisplayPort output of an MSI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 4G. The monitor is configured to use DisplayPort 1.2. I am running Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. The monitor works fine at full resolution (3840x2160 at 60 Hz in RGB mode).

I however suffer from the classic Windows+DisplayPort issue where Windows resets the position of all open windows to fit in a 1024x768 top-left rectangle whenever the monitor goes to sleep or is turned off (either manually or by Windows itself). This issue is well-known and well-documented, including here on Super User: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/630555/turning-displayport-monitor-off-disables-monitor-completely) [2](https://superuser.com/questions/267086/how-to-stop-windows-resizing-when-the-monitor-display-channel-is-turned-off-sw)

There is a [registry trick](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa?auth=1) that essentially allows to specify the resolution Windows should default to when no monitor is plugged. It does have an effect, and appears to be enough for most users.

Unfortunately, this trick is not sufficient with the PA328Q monitor. By connecting to my computer from another one via [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/), it appears that the monitor *first* switches to 2560x1600 for a split second before switching to full 3840x2160. This is enough to cause Windows to resize all windows to fit into a 2560x1600 rectangle.

ASUS tech support refuses to provide any support unless I first follow their "helpful instruction" to reinstall Windows.

**After weeks of investigation, I am desperate for any solution** that doesn't involve a shoddy program recording each and every windows move/resize actions in order to restore windows later.

EDIT: A detail that eluded me until now: during the brief instant where the display is in 2560x1600, the NVIDIA control panel reports that the monitor is connected through DVI (which it isn't, of course), and 2560x1600 appears to be the maximum resolution supported by DVI.

Comment: So, the issue is only appears when using TeamViewer for a few seconds before it goes to full screen ? is that right ?

Comment: @iSR5 That's not correct. The issue _always_ happen, even to this date.

Comment: Have you tried another DP cable ? or even tried HDMI cable ? just to make sure that the issue is only appears on DP and it's from the card DP!

Comment: Have more recent drivers and Windows versions resolved this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I would see if there is a way to disable Nvidia from even checking the DVI port or disable DVI from even working.

Comment: If you want to jump through ASUS tech support's hurdle to reinstall Windows you can create a new installation on an external drive and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It seems that with Windows 10 the problem no longer exists. I've had multiple installations of Windows 10 using this very monitor and I have other display issues but --as far as I understand-- they are related to Windows 10's _hidden window borders_ rather than being specific to this monitor.

Comment: That said I'm still on the lookout for any trick that would prevent Windows from noticing that a monitor connected via DisplayPort is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be solved with a UEFI DisplayPort firmware upgrade for your video card.

Here is the link to it.

Link: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/